# 怒りを通り越して sentence formation

Tags: grammar

彼はなんでもかんでも人のせいにする。あまりの理不尽さに怒りを通り越して呆れてしまう。

how did we make 怒りを通り越して this sentence pattern, can anyone explain it in detail.

Comment: Is your question about the meaning/structure of 怒りを通り越して or is it about how it fits into the sentence?

Comment: both explanation !!

Answer (score 3):

怒りを通り越して is a phrase that literally translates to go beyond anger. It's used to express situations where something is so bad or stupid, you don't even feel anger - it's gone to another level. This is my guess but the particle を　is used to denote the "space" for motion verbs. For example:

公園を歩く

壁を越える

So を marks the space , which is 怒り. 通り越す is a motion verb, though can be used for figurative expressions too, like 怒りを通り越して〜、バカを通り越して〜、信頼を通り越して〜.

**Sentence Structure**
It's in first person, or at least, it is written from the POV of the person who is speaking at this moment. So let's put that person back in:

彼はなんでもかんでも人のせいにする。（私は）あまりの理不尽さに怒りを通り越して呆れてしまう。

怒りを通り越して is linked to 呆れてしまう by て. て　has several uses but here, it's denoting V1 + V2 in that order. An example would be: 家に帰って寝る。

The person who is feeling this is 私. But it can be removed and the sentence would still mean more or less the same thing:

→ 私はあまりの理不尽さに呆れてしまう。

Source: http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/051.html

Comment: I wonder why this answer (and the question) got downvoted. I've read it and see little apparent error.

Comment: @broccoli forest well, it's the internet! anything can happen!